# Picture Gallery HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

I'm having trouble with image sizing in my gallery, I have been reading multiple threads and yt videos but can't seem to figure it out myself

image of the problem: [image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.des {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Veckans deals!</h1>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="vdeals_ett.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://topracingdrone.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/DJI-Phantom-4-Photogrammetry-Drone-300x184.png" alt="Drönare" width="300" height="200"></a>
    <div class="des">Add a desciption of the picture</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="vbild_two.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://topracingdrone.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Holy-Stone-HS100-UAV-photography-drone-300x176.png" alt="Drönare" width="300" height="200"></a>
    <div class="des">Add a desciption of the picture</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="vbild_tre.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://topracingdrone.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Parrot-Bebop-2-drone-300x143.jpeg" alt="Drönare" width="300" height="200"></a>
    <div class="des">Add a desciption of the picture</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="vbild_fyra.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://topracingdrone.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/GoPro-Hero-4-Silver-300x300.jpg" alt="Landskap" width="300" height="200"></a>
    <div class="des">Add a desciption of the picture</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way where you can make them all stretch while using `float`, without setting a fixed height to all images. You have three options.

1. Set a fixed height on the image and use `object-fit: cover` to make it look like it's stretching, while in fact it's covering it
2. Use flexbox with `flex-grow: 1` on the image ([see this example](http://www.lottejackson.com/learning/an-equal-height-grid-using-flexbox), recommended!)
3. Adjust all images to have the same width and height, if they can be made uniform.

Comment: This answer is correct, one small change is the object-fit:cover will crop the image to make it fit into the space while still maintaining the aspect ratio

Comment: Hello thanks for all the replys! where exactly should i insert this in my given code? (sorry for being little tard ;D )

Comment: Wrap everything in a div and make that a flexbox container (`display:flex;`). Remove the `responsive`-divs (not its contents) and apply `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to the `gallery`-divs. Then you only need to worry about the height of the images and the content.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding right away, im a newbie so when u say "everything" i get confused, and as i have used the CSS inside the HTML and not an external CSS, how i do this? i feel its not working the same way

Comment: CSS put inline within an HTML-tag works practically the same as if you would place CSS within a <style> tag in the <head> or in an external sheet. Only when you start to use both inline CSS and CSS in the <head>, then they might not, but that is not relevant now (in case you're interested though: search for 'css specificity'). To clarify: what I mean with 'everything' is to create a new `<div>` that will contain all `gallery`-divs, give this new div a class name like `gallery-container` and apply `display:flex` inline as a `style`. The `responsive`-divs are redundant in how this works.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that the images have different resolution.
First 2 images have the same resolution, 3:2 for example.
Last 2 images have the same resolution, 2:1 for example, but differs than first 2 images.
Please  try to fix the resolutions of images all the same.

Comment: Sometimes you can't change the image's aspect ratio's you get, and often, when there will be hundreds of photos, one will not want to adjust that all the time.

Comment: There are 3 options to display images:
1) displaying part of images using CSS
   In this case, grid looks great but visitors can't see the whole image.
2) displaying whole images using CSS
  In this case, visitors can see the whole image but grid doesn't look good.
3) displaying images keeping their ratio using grid library like masonry grid.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are not the same height/width, just like the ones I found you when I made you a snippet. So decide on which direction is important and use vh/vw and auto

[More here](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+vh+site:stackoverflow.com)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.gallery img {
  width: auto;
  height: 15vh;
}

.des {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Veckans deals!</h1>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="vdeals_ett.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://topracingdrone.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/DJI-Phantom-4-Photogrammetry-Drone-300x184.png" alt="Drönare" width="300" height="200"></a>
    <div class="des">Add a desciption of the picture</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="vbild_two.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://topracingdrone.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Holy-Stone-HS100-UAV-photography-drone-300x176.png" alt="Drönare" width="300" height="200"></a>
    <div class="des">Add a desciption of the picture</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="vbild_tre.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://topracingdrone.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Parrot-Bebop-2-drone-300x143.jpeg" alt="Drönare" width="300" height="200"></a>
    <div class="des">Add a desciption of the picture</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="vbild_fyra.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://topracingdrone.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/GoPro-Hero-4-Silver-300x300.jpg" alt="Landskap" width="300" height="200"></a>
    <div class="des">Add a desciption of the picture</div>
  </div>
</div>
```